# Heatmap small p-values

Tags: r, data-visualization, p-value

I'm experiencing some difficulties trying to manage too small p-values derived from a Fisher test. In particular I have p-values like: 2.220000e-121, 1.260000e-26, 1.260000e-334, and so on. The problem is that when I try to generate a heatmap of the values it seems not to take into account the differences between such too small numerical values. 
Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the heatmap, have you considered transforming the values? log(p) maybe?

Comment: Yes, I tried but they become <0.

Comment: If your heatmap library doesn't support negative numbers, what about abs(log(p))?

Comment: Ok I'm trying. I was not sure that was statistically correct. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: It seems from your question that you are trying to compare a set of p-values. This approach might not be very useful, especially given the extremely low p-values in your examples. See [this discussion](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21419/what-sense-does-it-make-to-compare-p-values-to-each-other) before you go too far down this road.